# Take a picture after BTLE background notification fired

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, avfoundation, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm developing an app that runs in background mode, so that my app receives BT notifications from a BTLE accessory.

When I get a specific notification, I want to take a picture whether the app is running in background or foreground.

**First question:** Would the app be rejected by Apple because of taking photos in background mode?

**Second question:**
What would be the best option to do this?

At first I thought about using UIImagePickerController, but finally I'm using AVFoundation [AVCam example](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVCam/History/History.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010112-RevisionHistory-DontLinkElementID_1) because I do not need to show preview.

But, **Third and last question:** could I show a preview?
I have tried to use the following code. It works ok if app is running in foreground mode, but not for background mode:

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iPhone5Storyboard" bundle:nil];
AVCamViewController *camViewController = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewControllerCamera"];

UIViewController *rootVC = [[(AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController];
[rootVC presentViewController: camViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Many doubts.

Answer (score 1):

First off, you cannot take a picture when the app is not in the foreground. That's just a core iOS limitation. (You could do it with a jailbroken iphone though).

As for the second part of your question, you AVFoundation is a great way to work with camera functionality. It's flexible on the view presentation and any type of filters you'd like to apply to the video stream. The AVCam example is a great example.

And for the third, that goes back to the first point. No matter what you use, you can't take pictures in the background unless it's in the foreground and the user has given permission.

I suggest submitting a local notification and asking the user to bring the app to the foregound when you want to take a picture. Probably not the news you wanted to hear, but that's how Apple intended it to be used.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I already take pictures when the app is in the background, but at the moment can show a preview only when the app is in the foreground. I do not use a jalibroken iphone. I'll consider your suggestion about submitting a notification.